# Test coverage in repo class using Ecto in Elixir

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, elixir, ecto

I have a very simple app in Elixir that uses Ecto, to run a SELECT query in a table on Postgres.
The table name is "person" and has 2 columns: "name" and "age".

This is the app:

```
/ecto_app
 |-application.ex
 |-repo.ex
```

application.ex:

```
defmodule EctoApp.Application do

  use Application

  require Logger

  @impl true
  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      EctoApp.Repo
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: EctoApp.Supervisor]
    Logger.debug("Starting Ecto App")
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

repo.ex:

```
defmodule EctoApp.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo,
    otp_app: :ecto_app,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres

  import Ecto.Query

  require Logger


  def get_people() do
    query = from p in "person",
            select: [p.name, p.age]
    result= EctoApp.Repo.all(query)
    Logger.debug(result)
  end

end
```

and I'm using this 2 libraries:

```
[
  {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.0"},
  {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"}
]
```

The app works fine, but the problem is that I want to make unit tests for the repo, but I can´t figure out how to Mock the Postgres connection, since I don´t want to start a Postgres instance to run the tests.

Did anyone knows how to Mock or which library I can use to "simulate" the connection to Postgres, so I can have test coverage on the repo class?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't just use the application.  Use the tests to do things you would do in the actual application.  The testing database doesn't persist records (or its meant not to) so you can really do whatever in there..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to mock the PostGres connection in the same way that you might mock other functionality.  This is because PostGres can wrap operations inside an undoable transaction.  The takeaway is that your tests use a *real* connection and make *real* requests against a *real* database, but the database is one dedicated to testing and issue queries via a special adapter.  This is by far the most common way to achieve test coverage for a database-backed app; attempting to mock the database connection makes for brittle tests rife with false positives, so it is not commonly done, especially when it is so simple to issue all your requests against a real database.

Here are the important bits to facilitate this in your code:

1. Specify the sandbox adapter and a dedicated test database in your app config, e.g. via config files:

```
# config/dev.exs
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  pool: DBConnection.ConnectionPool,
  database: "something_dev",
  # ... etc...

# config/test.exs
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  pool: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox,
  database: "something_test",
  # ... etc...
```

2. Your tests must checkout the `Repo` using the adapter prior to running queries. This is what wraps the actions in a transaction so you can safely re-run tests without excessive cleanup. A good place for this is inside the [setup callback](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/1.12/ExUnit.Callbacks.html), which runs prior to every test in the module:

```
defmodule MyApp.SomeTest do
  use ExUnit.Case # you may require async: false

  alias Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox
  alias MyApp.Repo

  setup do
    Sandbox.checkout(Repo)
  end

  describe "get_people/0" do
    test "select" do
      # insert fake records here
      assert [] = Repo.get_people()
    end
  end
end
```

A couple more pointers:

1. Your `get_people/0` function, as written, will not return the `result`. Remember that Elixir relies on implicit returns, so it returns the result of the last operation.  In your case, the thing returned will be the result of the *debug* statement, which is just an `:ok` and NOT the `result` you are expecting.
2. Don't forget that you may need to run migrations against your test database -- this isn't something that happens automagically.  You can make an alias in your `mix.exs` to execute `mix ecto.migrate` prior to tests, or you can just remember to run `MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.drop` etc. against the test database.
3. You'll often find it helpful to automatically build data "fixtures", i.e. fake records in the proper shape. The [ex_machina](https://hex.pm/packages/ex_machina) package is a handy way to do this, but no matter if you use a package or roll your own fixtures, your tests will need to prepare the database with whatever test records you expect as part of the "arrange" step in the standard "arrange-act-assert" methodology of testing.

If you circumstance truly requires that you mock the database *connection*, then I would recommend a simple pattern that relies on a kind of "dependency injection", e.g. where you can override the `Repo` module as a function parameter or as something pulled from config, e.g.

```
def get_people(repo \\ Repo)
  query = from p in "person",
    select: [p.name, p.age]
  repo.all(query)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! in my case definitely I need to mock the database, since at the moment the unit tests get executed, is not possible to have a real database, and I will see this: "could not lookup Ecto repo .. because it was not started or it does not exist". Maybe I can achieve this using this library: https://hex.pm/packages/mock

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest running PostgreSQL in a container, then using Ecto Sandbox. https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.html

Answer (score 0):

[ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) comes with its own testing suite and it has dedicated documentation on [How to Test with Ecto](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/testing-with-ecto.html).

[`Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.html) is to be used to test *but* there is no way to avoid starting the actual DB instance, mostly because it makes a very little sense to use mocked connections for testing.

Comment: I’ll leave this answer here for the sake of references, but obviously, the answer provided by @Everett is better, more complete, and should be chosen as the correct one.

Comment: I've had a negative experience using Sandbox.  It persists information in the database, so future tests expecting only what was inserted in that specific test to be in the database will fail.  Meaning if I decided to use Sandbox, I would have to write additional code to clean up the database after the tests are done running.